# FCM callback handler are not triggered after migration from gcm to fcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I migrated from GCM to FCM like instructed [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).

Whenever I send a message, the onMessageSent method is not invoked.

I use following source code to send messages:

```
Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
        data.put(GcmConstants.ACTION, GcmConstants.ACTION_CHAT);
        data.put(Constants.CHAT_FLAG, Constants.FLAG_NEW_CHAT);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String chatJsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(Helper.chatToJson(chat));

        data.put(Constants.CHAT_JSON, chatJsonInString);

        String receiverJsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(Helper.userToJson(receiver));
        data.put(Constants.RECEIVER_JSON, receiverJsonInString);

        String id = Integer.toString(getNextMsgId(ctxt));
        FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
        fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(senderId + "@gcm.googleapis.com").setMessageId(id).setData(data).build());
```

Why is not working?

Comment: Where are you sending from and to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the official website example [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java), then you will see this comment :

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

// TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
```

at the start of onMessageReceived. My understanding from this is that you must have a data component in your message, for the callback to be triggered.
I based my code on this and the callbacks are triggered.

Comment: but what about sent messages? Why is callback handler onMessageSent(String msgId) not triggered, when I send message like in the code sample above?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question, I read onMessageReceived for onMessagSent. Now, I don't think  my answer is going to help in any way.

Comment: No problem. Nevertheless, thank you for your comment.

Comment: At server side you got Success response?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I use a smack client for XMPP communiation. With GCM I received all messages, but now with FCM nothing seems to work. Do you have some server-side code? I can't find a client sample written in Java for  implementing server code on the web anywhere?

Comment: ok, problem solved. All I did wrong, was putting the google-services.json in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, solved my problem. I put google-services.json into the wrong folder. Next time I should following ["get started guide"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) for implementing the client more precisley.